# ES6 import / export not working with variables? Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

Why does this work

```
export var Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
```

But this doesn't?

```
var Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
export Tasks
```

Answer (score 3):

Because this is not a standard way of exporting variables. Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export):

```
export { name1, name2, …, nameN };
export { variable1 as name1, variable2 as name2, …, nameN };
export let name1, name2, …, nameN; // also var
export let name1 = …, name2 = …, …, nameN; // also var, const

export default expression;
export default function (…) { … } // also class, function*
export default function name1(…) { … } // also class, function*
export { name1 as default, … };

export * from …;
export { name1, name2, …, nameN } from …;
export { import1 as name1, import2 as name2, …, nameN } from …;
```

So what you can do is

```
export { Tasks };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax:

```
var Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
export { Tasks }
```

I'd also recommend using camelCase for variable names.

Comment: Thanks! 

Hmm makes sense too considering it's module.exports {Task} as well

I never use camelcase for mongo collections though

Comment: Best practice is `export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('Tasks');`

Comment: Yeah I'm just too used to node. using const is a habit I need to get into. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Best Practice for use  `export const Tasks = new Meteor.Collection('tasks');`